# Confusion in Sequential circuit

Tags: verilog, homework

[image]

I was asked to write a verilog code about the SLE shown in the picture above.
I have wrote the code until satisfying the condition of LAT=0, however the other half of the truth table I couldn't satisfy (I thought of making 2 always block that acts as a mux between the latch and the flip flop).
Can anybody can help me out or explain to me how can I implement it?

```
module question10(D,CLK,EN,ALn,ADn,SLn,SD,LAT,Q);
input D,CLK,EN,ALn,ADn,SLn,SD,LAT;
output reg Q;

always @(posedge CLK or negedge ALn)begin

  if (~ALn)begin
              Q<=!ADn;
           end
  else if (EN) begin
              if (~SLn)begin
                 Q<=SD;
              end else begin
                 Q<=D;
              end
        end
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?  Your problem statement seems to come from Microchip documentation, so why are you trying to-reimplement their functional block?  What do you want to use it for?  Why not implement what you actually *need*?

Comment: I am interested in this field and i am taking a course and the instructor told me to implement this SLE and truth table  however, i only came up to this conclusion on the code i wrote. yet it is still missing important stuff in which achieving the condition of LAT =1 i thought of making 2 always blocks acts as mux and i don't know how to make it

Comment: Oh and I forgot to add, I really didn't know that it was related to a a microchip documentation I just noticed it now.

Comment: There's no need for a mux. Instead of using ALn and ADn directly, you need to compute a more complex expression.

Comment: @dave_59 It seems really that I don't get it

Comment: This is a very "ugly" problem which mixes synchronous and asynchronous behavior in a way that HDL-type schools of logic design try very hard to avoid.  One almost wonders if the teacher really thought it through - if they did, they're hopefully trying to drive through a lesson about the challenges of such odd mode-mixing.

Comment: Why are you doing this? If it is a device model for simulation, so you can verify your own IP works correctly connected to it, you can write a much simpler behavioural model. If you need to synthesise it, that's a different matter.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I am using Modelsim for just a simple simulation and making a test bench to test the results. I am not using it to synthesise it

Comment: @ChrisStratton i was told by him a hint that to help me solve the problem, i would need 2 always blocks one for FF and the other for latch and implement them together